# Unir relatório do JasperReport com outros PDFs e imagens

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports, itext

Tenho um relatório JasperReport e preciso anexar a ele outros PDFs e imagens que o usuário anexou. Me sugeriram usar o iText, mas ainda não tenho ideia 
de como unir o pdf do relatório do Jasper com esses anexos. Como poderia implementar isso com iText? Eu conseguiria fazer isso com o próprio JasperReport?

Comment: Caso você tenha vários jaspers, você consegue combiná-los utilizando `JRPdfExporter`

Comment: Não são varios Jaspers, são um Jasper e vários pdfs e imagens que um usuário anexa

Comment: Tô querendo gerar um PDF com esses anexos e unir com o PDF do relatório

Comment: Entendi, com Jasper só é possível você incluir imagens, você não consegue incluir um PDF dentro dele. Com IText você consegue fazer isso utilizando [PdfCopy](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html)